# Auth token Python only generates string literal

Tags: python

```
token = jwt.encode({'some': email}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
```

Using: [Python JWT lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyJWT/1.4.0)

When I print

```
print(str(token))
```

I get something like: `b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9._ASviMFJ0oMbKs5CorloUx5FHE5MXz25OXNCQatAwho'`

So when I do comparison without the `b'` and `'` at the end, with this token above, it shows false. Why is this happening? How do I avoid it?

**Edit** I want to compare with `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9._ASviMFJ0oMbKs5CorloUx5FHE5MXz25OXNCQatAwho`

Comment: try using `bytes(token, 'utf-8')` to convert it to bytearray

Comment: @JurajBezručka, I got this weird thing: `b'&\xe7T\xe7\xc3\x1d'
b'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lIjoiZ2FybyJ9.s2dUTpG4TtUDQ2PVsShQ5y6Y578EdbVXuNNH1JSrZdA'
b't\xc2~\xc3\xfd\xd4'
b'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lIjoiZ2FybyJ9.s2dUTpG4TtUDQ2PVsShQ5y6Y578EdbVXuNNH1JSrZdA'
b"b'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9.2CrD3AsAL9QcWGUPbOm44jkSSL3jqX6R7u0fmfquabE'"`

Comment: @JurajBezručka, I have edited and shown what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
token = jwt.encode({'some': email}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
print token.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this works for me:

```
>>> token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9._ASviMFJ0oMbKs5CorloUx5FHE5MXz25OXNCQatAwho'
>>>bytearray(token, 'utf-8') == b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9._ASviMFJ0oMbKs5CorloUx5FHE5MXz25OXNCQatAwho'
True
```

The thing is that you compare bunch of bytes that are respresented in the form of characters with real string, so if you convert the string to bytes, then you can compare both.